# Algorithm to find the saddle point in a Binary tree

Tags: algorithms, binary-trees

How to find a saddle point in a binary tree. where saddle point is a node in a tree whose value = min(the node and all its ancestors) = max ( the node and all its descendants)

Comment: Such a node might not exist. For example consider tree with $3$ vertices: the root and its two children. The value of the root is $1$ and the value of the children are $2$ and $3$.

Comment: (With a (binary) [max heap](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max_heap), take any node.)

Comment: @Steven In case there is no node, we could retrieve that information. So if there is a saddle point, then the algorithm should output it; otherwise could return null, indicating there is no saddle point. I am not sure how to begin finding an algorithm for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sketch.

Given a node $u$, let $p_u,\ell_u,r_u,v_u$ denote its parent, it's left children, it's right children, and the value stored in $u$, respectively. Let $m(u)$ denote the minimum among all the values stored in the ancestors of $u$ ($u$ is an ancestor of itself). Let $M(u)$ denote the maximum among all the values stored in all the descendants of $u$ ($u$ is a descendant of itself).

Notice that $m(u) = \min\{v_u, m(p_u)\}$ and that $M(u)=\max\{ v_u, M(\ell_u), M(r_u)  \}$ and hence all values $m(\cdot)$ can be computed in linear time by a preorder visit, while all values $M(\cdot)$ can be computed in linear time by postorder visit.

Once you know $m(u)$ and $M(u)$ for a node $u$, you can check whether $u$ is a saddle. This should be more than enough to get you started. You can fill in the other details by yourself.